# How to set a breakpoint in Kotlin require with IntelliJ debugger?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

The Kotlin standard library has a neat function `require` which is something like a runtime `assert`:

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun require(value: Boolean, lazyMessage: () -> Any): Unit {
    contract {
        returns() implies value
    }
    if (!value) {
        val message = lazyMessage()
        throw IllegalArgumentException(message.toString())
    }
}
```

When I am debugging, I would like to be able to set a breakpoint in this function, just before the exception is thrown. Like this, I would have the entire stacktrace and local variables visible in the debugger once a requirement is broken. However, this doesn't seem to work:

[image]

At first I thought that this is because `require` is an `inline` function. I made an experiment with one of my `inline` functions and the debugger halts as expected.

As a workaround I tried to set the debugger to break on exceptions, but the framework I am working with (Spring) throws a barrage of exceptions on each application start, making it extremely tedious to ignore the irrelevant exceptions.

I would like to know **how** to make it work, but I am also interested about the **why** of "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's currently not possible to set breakpoints in Kotlin for functions marked with a *InlineOnly* annotation, and `require` is one of such functions. Inline functions marked with this annotation don't provide additional debug information in order to save a line from the call site untouched in stack-traces, but it also ruins setting breakpoints inside (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24306).

You have spotted one workaround - using exception breakpoints (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-exception-breakpoints.html). `IllegalArgumentException` would be the best class in this case.

If there're calls in your code that don't work, they might be replaced to custom function as another workaround.

*(The answer was updated. The previous version erroneously claimed that breakpoints in `require` might work for some calls.)*